# configuring mysql cluster server

Tags: mysql-cluster

Currently I have two servers:

1. appbe - linux server with apache web server.
2. db0 - linux server with mysql server.

I want to add another linux server with another mysql server and and to use mysql-cluster server instead.

I created a new linux server called db1 and i installed on both db0 and db1 that mysql cluster server.

my first question is:

I noticed the that MySQL Cluster Management Server Daemon be installed and running on one of the nodes. so I decided to install the Mysql Cluster management server on the appbe server as well. is it a good idea? will the cluster management server take too much resources and it shouldn't reside on the same server that supplies web pages? and if so doesn't it mean that I must have 3 different servers minimum to run mysql as a cluster ?

so it means that I'll have the following configuration:

appbe - tomcat web server with mysql management node

- db1 - data node
- db2 - data node

by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Cluster
I understood that running that SQL node (running mysql server) is optional and is not needed
if I use the NDB API. I read that clusterJ connector uses that API.

is that an optimal configuration ? if db1 and db2 are data nodes doesn't it mean that the management node is the brain and all the sql parsing will happen there?

any information would be greatly appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Have you ever read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster.html) or [books](http://www.amazon.com/MySQL-High-Availability-Building-Centers/dp/0596807309/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1317583082&sr=8-1) about that topic beside a broad Wikipedia article?

Comment: From your question I assume you don't want to use MySQL Cluster, but maybe some MySQL replication, if really needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth taking a look at the MySQL Cluster evaluation guide to get an overview of the technology and recommended deployment:
http://mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_cluster_eval_guide.php